# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'img' of null

Tags: reactjs, image

I am making api calls to receive images and certain calls do not have actual images and so I believe I am getting these values of null that are causing react to throw an error. I have tried using an onError method in my code to place a fallback image but that did not work as well. I have tried handling this error with a ternary expression as well but have not had any luck. My question is what is the best way to get rid of this error and provide a default image in cases where I receive null.

This is the line of code where I am getting an error:

```
       <img
        className="cover-photo"
        src={this.props.detail.img}
        alt={this.props.detail.caption}
       />
```

Comment: Try something like this:
`src={this.props.detail.img || "path/to/default/image"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can check if `this.props.detail` is null and set a default. This is using the conditional (ternary) operator

```
   <img
    className="cover-photo"
    src={this.props.detail ? this.props.detail.img : "/default/img/path.png"}
    alt={this.props.detail ? this.props.detail.caption : ""}
   />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator